# how to get http POST response

Tags: html, jquery

I'm looking for a way to get the response from an HTTP POST without using a library. I've found this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post) on w3schools.com using jQuery's $.post method where you pass in a function to handle the response. I've tried looking at jQuery's source to figure out how it's handling it but I haven't gotten anywhere with that.

my POST response will be a json object that I will parse and display on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, I wasn't thinking.  You could use the native javascript ajax controls.  Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

There are examples listed below showing you how to submit form data; I'm not sure if there's an event fired when the status changes or not.  You'll have to dig a little bit in their examples.

Comment: That looks like it, I need to call xmlhttp.responseText. Thank you, I've been searching w3schools.com for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: I remember "learning AJAX" a while back, before I knew things like jQuery existed (they were still new).  I quickly decided to just wait for something better to come along.  Lol.